# default value does not stick in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I have this field `IsTrial` in MySQL of type `bit(1)` with `NULL set to No` and `default value of 0`

[image]

Now this condition:

```
if(!empty($subscription['IsTrial']) && (bool)$subscription['IsTrial'] == TRUE ) 
{ 
    echo ' (Trial)'; 
}
```

.. it ALWAYS turns out `true`, because mysql doesn't actually set the default value of `0`, it keeps the field BLANK?? To make the above condition work, I have to set the default value in the MYSQL from `0` to `null`, but I do not want to do that.

I'm really confused whats going on here, why would the default value `0` be not set and the field remains blank?

To reiterate, **the issue is, mysql does NOT save the field with default value `0` when no value is manually specified, it keeps the field BLANK which causing the conditions to fail.**

Comment: well you set the value manually. The issue is, mysql does NOT save the  field with default value of `0` when no value is specified yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field is not blank.  It has the **binary** value 0.

You didn't define the default value to `0`, i.e. the character with ASCII code 48.  You defined the default value to the binary value 0, which is the `nul` character in ASCII.  When you try to print ASCII nul as a string, there is no visible representation.   Likewise a value `1` is binary value 1, or Control-A, which is not a printing character either.

```
mysql> create table t (isTrial bit(1) not null default 0);

mysql> insert into t () values ();
mysql> insert into t (isTrial) values (DEFAULT);
mysql> insert into t (isTrial) values (0);
mysql> insert into t (isTrial) values (1);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t;
+---------+
| isTrial |
+---------+
|         |
|         |
|         |
|        |
+---------+

mysql> pager cat -v
PAGER set to 'cat -v'
mysql> select * from t;
+---------+
| isTrial |
+---------+
|         |
|         |
|         |
| ^A       |
+---------+
```

But PHP does what most users probably want, which is to map these BIT values to the **string** values "0" and "1" respectively.  Here's some test code (using PHP 5.3.15, MySQL 5.5.30):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select isTrial from t");
$result = $stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row);
    if(!empty($row['isTrial']) && (bool)$row['isTrial'] == TRUE ) 
    { 
        echo "isTrial is true\n";
    } else {
        echo "isTrial is false\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ php bit.php
array(1) {
  ["isTrial"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
isTrial is false

array(1) {
  ["isTrial"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
isTrial is false

array(1) {
  ["isTrial"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
isTrial is false

array(1) {
  ["isTrial"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
isTrial is true
```

---

Re your comment:

Using BIT(1) should work fine for PHP, but it causes confusion when we look at the data directly in the query tool.  If you want to make the data more clear, you can use TINYINT.  Another option would be CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET ASCII.  Both require 1 byte for storage.

The only advantage of BIT(1) is that it rejects any value besides 0 or 1.  But the storage requirement for this data type rounds up to 1 byte anyway.

Comment: So you mean I should use `tinyint` instead of `bit` in this case?